# Example for AssumeRolewithSAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, federated-identity, assume-role

I would like to get a full flow of this AssumeRolewithSAML mechanism but am not getting a real example for this. I understand the concept but something like a working model example i would like to see. Any leads for this.? TIA. 
[For Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_saml.html)

Comment: Do you plan using the Cognito or are you building your own identity broker?

Comment: not cognito. we have our own idp. i need to send SAML assertion from idp.

Comment: And where is the problem? What is not clear or not working?